# Issue with scale_color_identity() in ggplot -- labels reordered automatically by colour name

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I want to control my font colour using explicitly named colours in the `label_col` column. However, it seems that the colours "black" and "white" end up being ordered alphabetically by the colour name, instead of following the same fill and position specified in `ggplot(aes())` and `geom_col()`.

Here is my minimal example with black and white:

```
list_order <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")

test <- data.frame(indicator = rep(list_order, 2),
                   mean = c(1.1, 0.3, 6.3, 4, 7, 2.1, 1.2, 0.7, 6.9, 3.3, 5.4, 1.8),
                   group = c(rep("Group A", 6), rep("Group B", 6)))

test %>% 
  mutate(indicator = factor(indicator, levels = list_order),
         label = round(mean, 1),
         label_col = ifelse(indicator %in% c("a", "d", "e", "f"), "black", "white")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = group, y = mean, fill = indicator)) +
  geom_col(width = 0.7, position = "stack") +
  geom_text(aes(label = label, color = label_col), size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_color_identity() +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = T, option = "plasma")
```

Which gives me this:
[image]

If I change the colours in `label_col` to both "white", or both "black", I get them in the correct places like here:

[image]

[image]

Is there something I am not understanding about how ggplot positions labels and text? I know how to work around this by using `scale_color_manual()`, but would also like to understand why `scale_color_identity()` is not working here, and the solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with no explicit grouping of variables. I modified your code by adding `group = group` to aesthetics specification and it seem to work.

I am not entirely sure where specifically lies the problem, but I assume that the problem is with some reordering done under the hood -- you can see in your example that all white labels are brought to the bottom and all black are brought to the top.

```r
test %>% 
  mutate(indicator = factor(indicator, levels = list_order),
         label = round(mean, 1),
         label_col = ifelse(indicator %in% c("a", "d", "e", "f"), "black", "white")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = group, y = mean, fill = indicator, group = group)) +
  geom_col(width = 0.7, position = "stack") +
  geom_text(aes(label = label, color = label_col), size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_color_identity() +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = T, option = "plasma")
```

Comment: Thank you! This works, though I'm not sure why either as group is on the x-axis and shouldn't have any bearing on the order of the labels within groups... Anyway, the issue is that the order seems to be alphabetical by the name of the colour. If you change "white" to "black" and vice-versa, or use "green" or "red" or any other colour, they will appear by their names alphabetically from top to bottom. Perhaps something to do with `position = "stack"`?